# Parse whereKey matchesKey conundrum

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So... using [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/) with Swift.

I have a class called "**Causes**" and a class called "**Supporters**".

Supporters has two pointer fields - '*causesPtr*' which points to the cause that is supported, and '*fromUser*' which points to the user that supports the cause.

I query my **Supporters** class like this:

```
    let supportersQuery = PFQuery(className: "Supporters")
    supportersQuery.whereKey("fromUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
```

Now, I want to query the Causes class, and only return the ones that match the results of the first query... so:

```
    let causesQuery = PFQuery(className: "Causes")
    causesQuery.whereKey("objectId", matchesKey: "causesPtr", inQuery: supportersQuery)
```

... and of course this doesn't work, where the key in causes is a String, and the matching key from the first query is actually a PFObject... I get that.

But I am at a conceptual loss of how to properly construct this query in order to match what I am trying to achieve.

Of course, I could save the objectId of the Cause in the Supporters class instead of the pointer to the object, but I think that pointers is a better solution. Or can I actually pull the objectId of the pointer in the query ?

It's late... very well might be missing something!
Thanks!

Comment: Just add `includeKey:"causesPtr"` to your `supportersQuery` and then execute that query. The `causesPtr` will be your causes PFObject

Comment: No... the equalTo in the supportersQuery already returns the PFObject. My issue is how to filter the causesQuery to only the matching objects returned from the supportersQuery ...

Comment: your first query returns the rows from the Supporters class for the current user. The `causesPtr` in each of these rows will be the Causes PFObject that is supported. What else do you want?

Comment: ... right. so I just need to cast that pointer coming out of the first query. duh.

Comment: if you want to add your comment as an answer, I can accept it... otherwise i will delete the question.

Comment: I will add an answer later. It is a worthwhile question. SO is about helping others in the future who may have a similar issue as well as getting an answer for your own problem